# Uncaught Error: No value passed to payment

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

ASP.Net Framework 4.5.2 on Windows

I am configuring my integration with paypal using **Server-side REST**, my code is the same that this https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/blob/develop/Samples/Source/PaymentWithPayPal.aspx.cs, no diference.

### Payment model

The Payment model created are this:

```
{"intent":"sale","payer":{"payment_method":"paypal"},"transactions":[{"amount":{"currency":"USD","total":"100.00","details":{"subtotal":"75","shipping":"10","tax":"15"}},"description":"Transaction description.","invoice_number":"608961","item_list":{"items":[{"sku":"sku","name":"Item Name","quantity":"5","price":"15","currency":"USD"}]}}],"redirect_urls":{"return_url":"http://localhost:51379/PaymentWithPayPal.aspx?guid=60896","cancel_url":"http://localhost:51379/PaymentWithPayPal.aspx?guid=60896&cancel=true"}}
```

#### After Payment model is created

I create the payment at this line

```
var createdPayment = payment.Create(apiContext);
```

### CreatedPayment

And the createdPayment variable is equals to:

```
{"id":"PAY-8TG15254J2564684XLFQUQHQ","intent":"sale","payer":{"payment_method":"paypal"},"transactions":[{"related_resources":[],"amount":{"currency":"USD","total":"100.00","details":{"subtotal":"75.00","shipping":"10.00","tax":"15.00"}},"description":"Transaction description.","invoice_number":"608961","item_list":{"items":[{"sku":"sku","name":"Item Name","quantity":"5","price":"15.00","currency":"USD"}]}}],"state":"created","create_time":"2017-07-08T21:01:18Z","links":[{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-8TG15254J2564684XLFQUQHQ","rel":"self","method":"GET"},{"href":"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-6PE445186E489192C","rel":"approval_url","method":"REDIRECT"},{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-8TG15254J2564684XLFQUQHQ/execute","rel":"execute","method":"POST"}]}
```

### Error

after, the code continues without any error, and when it finish, the paypal window closes and I am getting the next error on javascript:
**Error: No value passed to payment**

```
Object {stack: "Error: No value passed to payment↵ at https://w…://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:2390:13)", errtype: "[object Error]", timestamp: 1499547706746, windowID: "5148517b93", pageID: "510d0e1522"…} country:"US" env:"sandbox" errtype:"[object Error]" host:"www.sandbox.paypal.com" lang:"en" pageID:"510d0e1522" path:"/webapps/hermes/button" referer:"http://localhost:51379" stack:"Error: No value passed to payment↵ at https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:7986:52↵ at https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:7417:54↵ at ZalgoPromise.dispatch (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:7441:27)↵ at ZalgoPromise.resolve (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:7386:22)↵ at https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:7363:48↵ at https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:7417:54↵ at ZalgoPromise.dispatch (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:7441:27)↵ at ZalgoPromise.resolve (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:7386:22)↵ at https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:7440:42↵ at ZalgoPromise.dispatch (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:7441:27)↵ at Object._RECEIVE_MESSAGE_TYPE.(anonymous function) [as postrobot_message_response] (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:2471:118)↵ at receiveMessage (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:2369:77)↵ at messageListener (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:2390:13)" timestamp : 1499547706746 uid : "8cb15883be" ver : "4.0.89" windowID : "5148517b93" __proto__ : Object
```

### This is my PayPal CheckoutJS

```
paypal.Button.render({
        env: 'sandbox',
        commit: true,
        payment: function () {

            // Set up a url on your server to create the payment
            var CREATE_URL = "@Url.Action("MakePaymentWithPayPal", "Payment")";

            // Make a call to your server to set up the payment
            return paypal.request.post(CREATE_URL)
                .then(function (res) {
                    console.log("res");
                    console.log(res);//this is always empty
                    return res.paymentID;
                }).catch(function (err) {
                    reject("err");
                    reject(err);
                });
        },
        onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {

            // Set up a url on your server to execute the payment
            var EXECUTE_URL = '/demo/checkout/api/paypal/payment/execute/';

            // Set up the data you need to pass to your server
            var data = {
                paymentID: data.paymentID,
                payerID: data.payerID
            };

            // Make a call to your server to execute the payment
            return paypal.request.post(EXECUTE_URL, data)
                .then(function (res) {
                    window.alert('Payment Complete!');
                    console.log(res);
                });
        }
    }, '#paypal-button');`
```

Comment: Can you please share your client-side code? Are you passing back the `PAY-XXXXXX` id to the payment() function directly?

Comment: Ready!, I was edited the question.

Comment: Is your server returning valid json in the response, with `content-type: application/json`? Can you check in the chrome network tab?

Comment: The response headers are only these
`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcc3RldmVcRG9jdW1lbnRzXEdpdEh1YlxBTWVtb3J5Rm9yRXZlclxBTWVtb3J5Rm9yRXZlclxQYXltZW50XE1ha2VQYXltZW50V2l0aFBheVBhbA==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 12 Jul 2017 22:40:26 GMT
Content-Length: 0`

Comment: `Content-Length: 0` -- so there's no response body?

Comment: At the sample, the method doesn't have return type, only at the end it add the payment Id to session data
`Session.Add(guid, createdPayment.id);
                Session.Add("flow-" + guid, this.flow);`

Comment: Right... so you do actually need to return the `id` to the client side in the response to the request to `CREATE_URL`, otherwise the client side has no way of knowing the id and opening the paypal popup with the correct url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Thanks to [bluepnume](https://stackoverflow.com/users/177511/bluepnume) for open my eyes**

I changed the method from Void type to String type => this change is for return the response from my server to Client-Side js

At the end of the create payment code, I added one line to save the guid number and the return

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("guid", guid); //we need this number on authorize payment
HttpContext.Current.Session.Add(guid, createdPayment.id);
HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("flow-" + guid, this.flow);
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(createdPayment, Formatting.None); //I return the created payment
```

Now at the JS I changed the return by the correct payment id

```
        payment: function () {
            var CREATE_URL = "@Url.Action("MakePaymentWithPayPal", "Payment")";
            return paypal.request.post(CREATE_URL)
                .then(function (res) {
                    //return res.paymentID; //earlier line
                    return res.id;
                });
        },
```

And at the begin of the authorize payment code, I exchange the line with which the guid was retrieved to continue the transaction and at the end I return the executed payment

```
//var guid = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["guid"]; //earlier line
string guid = HttpContext.Current.Session["guid"].ToString();

//code...

return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(executedPayment, Formatting.None);
```

and this is ready to make payments.